# How to set/use env vars in Electron's `main.js` when using electron-builder?

Tags: node.js, electron, environment, electron-builder

I'm trying to make my `loadUrl(process.env.HOMEPAGE_URL)`.

If I load env vars via CLI like so `"pack": "env $(cat .env | xargs) yarn build && electron-builder"` then run yarn pack it doesn't actually load any page it seems.

I've tried duplicating `.env` as `electron-builder.env` and putting that in various folders, but get the same result.

Please tell me what I'm missing? It seems like this would be a really common pattern but I'm not finding a solution.